# making multi language website by php

Tags: php, internationalization

I have a question about creating a multi language website which also allow the administrator of website to add new languages or edit languages words . 
I was wondering if it's a good idea to store all of the languages inside database and according to user language , get all of the words from database and put them  in an array  ?

If not , what are other solutions?

The most important part is that the administrator has the ability to add new language .

Thanks

Comment: http://www.bitrepository.com/php-how-to-add-multi-language-support-to-a-website.html

Answer (score 0):

As long as translating static content the gettext utility is the way to go. It solves all translation related problems and let you keep you templates free from unnecessary code. The translation of a dynamic content can be done many ways. First of all the translation of dynamic content should never stay in static resources, instead it should be kept together with the content as it is (just like the pretty url) part of the items. Any solution that would create new tables or fields for each language would create one-to-one relations or duplicate structural informations, both which can hurt performance and simplicity. Creating a new column that stores the id of the original language can be a solution but it requires an other (sub)query for the translations and that each item will have a base language. If the pretty urls are used as unique keys and the urls are translated then this might be the right solution. Otherwise if the unique keys are not translated you can even just change them to include the language column, allowing you to query directly for the translated version of each item, but an other (sub)query will be necessary to find the item in an other language in case in the requested one it doesn't exist. The decision between this last two method depend on the nature of the data.